# Why does this simple usage of Python's subprocess hang?

Tags: python, subprocess

```
import subprocess

proc1 = subprocess.Popen(['cat'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
proc2 = subprocess.Popen(['cat'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

proc1.stdin.close()
proc1.wait()
```

When running this on Debian with Python 2.6.6, the program never exits. The strange thing is when I change the last two lines to use `proc2`, it does exit.

What's going on here?

Comment: Can't reproduce. Exits cleanly without output either way on Windows 7 with Python 2.7 (but run in bash using MSYS)

Comment: subprocess uses different internal implementations (unsurprisingly) on POSIX and Windows. Reproducible on Gentoo w/ 2.6 and 3.1.

Comment: The guys at #python-dev think this is a bug, I opened one: http://bugs.python.org/issue12786

Answer (score 0):

Try typing "cat" with no arguments in a terminal. "cat" requires something to concatenate to the stdout.

```
>>> from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
>>> args = ["cat", "foobar"]
>>> reply = Popen(args, stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0]
>>> print (reply)
line 0
line 1
line 2

>>>
```

Docs have a pretty good set of use examples:

http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline

Comment: If you want the reply to be a nice list, just do reply = reply.strip().split("\n")

Comment: Err ... not sure why this got a down vote. Was there something wrong with the answer?

Comment: the down vote didn't come from me, but it's wrong nonetheless, try running `cat` with no arguments in your terminal and then send an EOF (by pressing Ctrl-D for example).

Comment: Are you sending an EOF to your Popen object?

Comment: try this:>>> args = ["cat"]
>>> reply = Popen(args, stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0]

Comment: You are never actually executing your stdin.close() since it's hanging waiting for something to cat to do.

Comment: Replaying it line-by-line in shell, it really hangs on `wait()` (CPython 2.6, Ubuntu 10.10).

Comment: Ah! I see what you mean. I guess there is something to be said for trying the actual example given rather than assuming that the querent did not understand how to use Popen. :-) I tried this as well: proc1 = Popen(["cat"], stdout=PIPE), which causes the interpreter to get very laggy and/or hang in Ubuntu. Why are you calling "cat" in this way?

Comment: This doesn't explain why the following works just fine: p1 = Popen("cat", stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE); p2=Popen("cat", stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE); p2.stdin.close(); p2.wait().